# Y-Axis ticks on Right Side of Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple line plot and need to move the y-axis ticks from the (default) left side of the plot to the right side. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Use `ax.yaxis.tick_right()`

for example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
plt.plot([2,3,4,5])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, you get a +1, I'd give you another +1 for the picture but I'm limited to only 1.

Comment: interesting that this causes the tick names to come back even though they should be suppressed by sharey=True

Comment: And what if I want the ticks and labels both left and right?

Comment: I did not sort out why, but this breaks if you have subplots with `sharey=True`.

Comment: What's the command to make the ticks appear on the left *and* the right? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using plt to plot try `plt.gca().yaxis.tick_right()`

Answer (score 131):

For right labels use `ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")`, i.e.:

```
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
plt.plot([2,3,4,5])
ax.set_xlabel("$x$ /mm")
ax.set_ylabel("$y$ /mm")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 70):

joaquin's answer works, but has the side effect of removing ticks from the left side of the axes. To fix this, follow up `tick_right()` with a call to `set_ticks_position('both')`. A revised example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
plt.plot([2,3,4,5])
plt.show()
```

The result is a plot with ticks on both sides, but tick labels on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Just is case somebody asks (like I did), this is also possible when one uses subplot2grid. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,1), rowspan=3)
plt.plot([2,3,4,5])
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft='off', labelright='on')
plt.show()
```

It will show this:

[image]

Comment: This works with `ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft='off', labelright='on')` as well. But it does not move the `ylabel`

Comment: Well you can always use `plt.gca()` to get the current axes object. Therefore you would use: `plt.gca().yaxis.set_label_position("right")`

Comment: `labelleft, labelright : bool`. So it should be `plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft=False, labelright=True)` to disable left-side labels. Also `left=False, right=True` to move ticks as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using **subplots** and if you are sharing the y-axis (i.e., `sharey=True`), before creating the plot, try:

`plt.rcParams['ytick.right'] = plt.rcParams['ytick.labelright'] = True`
`plt.rcParams['ytick.left'] = plt.rcParams['ytick.labelleft'] = False`

From: [Matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick_label_right.html)

Comment: Works neatly in 2022 with current version of matplotlib.