# Restore left ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question similar to:
[Python Matplotlib Y-Axis ticks on Right Side of Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354397/python-matplotlib-y-axis-labels-on-right-side-of-plot)

I fixed the problem of putting y-axis ticklabels on the right side of the plot, but I would like to restore y ticks on the left side too.

I tried with:

```
yax.set_ticks_position('both')
```

but I get:

```
ax0.set_ticks_position('both')
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_ticks_position'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the right object on which to call `set_ticks_position()`. Here's a simpler way with `gca()`:

```
from pylab import *

figure()
plot(arange(5))
ax = gca()
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
```

[image]

Comment: Tiago, I fixed the problem using ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both') without gca(). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In the second code sample you use `ax0`, which I guess is an `Axes` instance, in the first code sample you use `yax`, which presumably the  axis-child of `ax0`.

I think you're looking for [tick_params](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params): `ax0.tick_params(axis = 'y', direction = 'in')`