# overlapping tick labels on plot consisting of several axis - tight_layout not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a plot constructed by the code

```
left, width = 0.1, 0.8
rect1 = [left, 0.7, width, 0.2]
rect2 = [left, 0.3, width, 0.4]
rect3 = [left, 0.1, width, 0.2]
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect1)
ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect2,sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_axes(rect3,sharex=ax1)
```

The max-y-tick-labels of the outer axis (x1,x2) overlap with the max-tick-labels of the inner plot (ax2) which is marked by the red eclipses in the following image:

[image]

How can that be prevented, if

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

doesn't work?

Comment: Did you try to change the size of your figure ?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the y-labels manually, using

```
 ax1.set_yticks([30, 70])
```

the overlap can be prevented.

This solution is not completely satisfying however, since it is hardcoded and not very generic. But it works for this specific problem.

Another solution would be to move the y-labels of the middle axis to the right side, as suggested in

[Python Matplotlib Y-Axis ticks on Right Side of Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354397/python-matplotlib-y-axis-ticks-on-right-side-of-plot?rq=1)