# adjust matplotlib subplot spacing after tight_layout

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to minimize white space in my figure. I have a row of sub plots where four plots share their y-axis and the last plot has a separate axis.
There are no ylabels or ticklabels for the shared axis middle panels.

`tight_layout` creates a lot of white space between the the middle plots as if leaving space for tick labels and ylabels but I would rather stretch the sub plots. Is this possible?

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 5, width_ratios=[4,1,4,1,2]) 

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
axes = [ax] + [fig.add_subplot(gs[i], sharey=ax) for i in range(1, 4)]

axes[0].plot(np.random.randint(0,100,100))
barlist=axes[1].bar([1,2],[1,20])

axes[2].plot(np.random.randint(0,100,100))
barlist=axes[3].bar([1,2],[1,20])

axes[0].set_ylabel('data')

axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gs[4]))
axes[4].plot(np.random.randint(0,5,100))
axes[4].set_ylabel('other data')


for ax in axes[1:4]:
    plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)


sns.despine();
plt.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `w_pad = 0` is not changing the default settings of `tight_layout`. You need to set something like `w_pad = -2`. Which produces the following figure:

[image]

You could go further, to say `-3` but then you would start to get some overlap with your last plot.

Another way could be to remove `plt.tight_layout()` and set the boundaries yourself using

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.065, right=0.97, top=0.96, bottom=0.065, wspace=0.14)
```

Though this can be a bit of a trial and error process.

**Edit**

A nice looking graph can be achieved by moving the ticks and the labels of the last plot to the right hand side. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354397/python-matplotlib-y-axis-ticks-on-right-side-of-plot) answer shows you can do this by using:

```
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
```

So for your example:

```
axes[4].yaxis.tick_right()
axes[4].yaxis.set_label_position("right")
```

In addition, you need to remove `sns.despine()`. Finally, there is now no need to set `w_pad = -2`, just use `plt.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0)`

Using this creates the following figure:

[image]

Comment: thanks! this looks better but there already is substantial overlap of the last ylabel with the bars of the second to last panel. I was hoping there would be some way of giving just that last panel more horizontal space?

Comment: the problem actually gets worse with larger font size as in my example

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure if you can do that (at least I don't know of the top of my head). There may be a non-trivial solution which somebody else might know. A work around _could_ be to move your ticks and labels of the last plot to the right hand side?

Comment: @jlarsch See my updated answer for another possible solution

Comment: sorry for being such a pain. I really like this improved version but I would love to have axes lines and ticks along the labeled edges of all panels. Basically exactly the aesthetics of my plot above but with the last axis on the left. I have tried to use `sns.set_style('ticks')` but then I cannot remove the spines and `sns.despine()` keeps reverting the axis to the left...

Comment: OK, I managed by using `sns.set_style('ticks')` and manually setting the unwanted spines to be of background colour and setting `set_ticks_position` to `bottom`.