# ticks on right side of plot un subplots enviroment

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, axes

I am trying to get the ticks for my plot on the right side. (The one int he lower right corner) I've tried many of the related topics. eg. 
[Python Matplotlib Y-Axis ticks on Right Side of Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354397/python-matplotlib-y-axis-ticks-on-right-side-of-plot)
[matplotlib y-axis label on right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369888/matplotlib-y-axis-label-on-right-side/13369977)

But nothing seems to work. Could someone take a look if I by any chance am doing something wrong with the ax environment? I am on python 2.7 btw.

```
step_1 = step_2 = step_3 = step_4 = step_5 = np.random.random((300,300))
u1 = u2 = u3 = u4 = u5 = wav = np.random.random(30)
o = 20

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})
(ax1, ax2, ax3),(ax4, ax5, ax6) = axs

im1 = ax1.imshow(step_1, origin='lower', cmap='gray', extent=[xb,xe,yb,ye], aspect='auto')
#630,475 = 81,-546
ax1.scatter(-555,70, marker='x', color='red')
ax1.set_xticklabels([])

im2 = ax2.imshow(step_2, origin='lower', cmap='gray', extent=[xb,xe,yb,ye], aspect='auto')
ax2.scatter(-555,70,marker='x', color='red')
ax2.set_yticklabels([])

im3 = ax3.imshow(step_3, origin='lower', cmap='gray', extent=[xb,xe,yb,ye], aspect='auto')
ax3.scatter(-555,70,marker='x', color='red')
ax3.set_yticklabels([])

im4 = ax4.imshow(step_4, origin='lower', cmap='gray', extent=[xb,xe,yb,ye], aspect='auto')
ax4.scatter(-555,70,marker='x', color='red')


im5 = ax5.imshow(step_5, origin='lower', cmap='gray', extent=[xb,xe,yb,ye], aspect='auto')
ax5.scatter(-555,70,marker='x', color='red')
ax5.set_yticklabels([])



im6 = ax6.plot(wav, u1/o, label='Step 1', color='lightcoral', alpha=0.6)
ax6.plot(wav, u2/o, label='Step 2', color='indianred', alpha=0.7)
ax6.plot(wav, u3/o, label='Step 3', color='brown', alpha=0.8)
ax6.plot(wav, u4/o, label='Step 4', color='firebrick', alpha=0.9)
ax6.plot(wav, u5/o, label='Step 5', color='darkred', linewidth=3.)
ax6.legend()
ax6.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(-2,2))
ax6.xlabel('Wavelength ($\mathrm{\AA}$)')
ax6.yaxis.tick_right()
ax6.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You code works fine for me apart from the line `ax6.xlabel('Wavelength ($\mathrm{\AA}$)')` which needs to be `ax6.set_xlabel('Wavelength ($\mathrm{\AA}$)')`

Comment: Try this `ax6.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft='off', labelright='on')` as per  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23139965/4932316) answer

Comment: The ax moved now that I fixed the xlabel, but the numbers are gone. Also the 2nd one does not work.

Comment: Got it! Had to add `ax6.update_ticks()`

Answer (score 0):

So what worked was to add `ax6.update_ticks()` to the end of the script. This was python 2.7.